# twitter bootstrap 3 columns stacking

Tags: laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have my markup setup to show a 3 column twitter bootstrap layout, but instead the divs are stacking. This should be real simple and I cannot figure out why the columns are not being columns.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="header">

            <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4">

                <a href="{{ URL::route('home') }}">

                <div class="header_group">
                <img src="../../images/me.png">
                <span><h1 class="header_text">Logo</h1></span>
                </div><!--header group -->
                </a>

            </div>

            <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4">
            middle
            </div>

            <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4">
            @include('layout.navigation')
            </div>


        </div><!-- main header -->
        </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the dots before the class names

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="header">    

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">    
                Column1    
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                Column 2
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                Column3
            </div>

          </div><!-- header -->

      </div><!-- row -->
 </div><!-- container -->
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1389/)